# How to merge two sets of data/array dynamically based on their count

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm, dataset, data-extraction

So, I have this requirement that I have two sets of data (stored in arrays, but can be anything). What I want to do is that I want to add these two sets together so that the final result count is 10.

The scenarios are:

1. Both sets can initially have more than 5 (or 10 for that matter). In which case it is easy - I just take 5 from each set and add them together and display
2. Either set could be less than 5. In which case, I should take whatever is available in that set. In the other set, I should take how-much-ever is required to make total 10, If the other set's count is low such that taking it does not make total to 10, then I should take it all and display whatever I got.

Based on this requirement, I am trying to write a logic which will give me the count required from each set, however the `if-else-if-else` is getting too complicated that I think I might be doing it incorrectly. Can anyone help me with creating a simpler logic to do what I need?

My current (incomplete and convoluted) logic is:

```
if($set1Count >= 5)
{
    $requiredSet1Count = 5;
    if($set2Count >= 5)
    {
        $requiredSet2Count = 5;
    }
    else
    {
        $requiredSet2Count = $set2Count;
        if($requiredSet1Count > = (10 - $set2Count))
        {
            $requiredSet1Count = (10 - $set2Count);
        }
        else
        {
            $requiredSet1Count = $set1Count;
        }
    }
}
else
{
    .....// I gave up by the time I reached here....
}
```

In above code `$set1Count` and `$set2Count` are the actual result counts in the two sets/arrays. The `$requiredSet1Count`and `$requiredSet2Count` are the dynamic counts I need which will tell me how many elements to extract from each set.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know a variant without ifs. Lets try to use one for every situation

```
function requiredSet($set1count, $set2count) {
// Both arrays together contain less than 10 items
    if ($set1count + $set2count <= 10) { 
        $requiredSet1Count  = $set1count;  $requiredSet2Count = $set2count;
    }
// 1st less than 5 elements
    elseif ($set1count < 5) {
        $requiredSet1Count  = $set1count;
        $requiredSet2Count  = $set2count + $set1count > 10 ? 10 - $set1count : $set2count;
    }
// 2nd - less than 5 elements
    elseif ($set2count < 5) {
        $requiredSet2Count  = $set2count;
        $requiredSet1Count  = $set1count + $set2count > 10 ? 10 - $set2count : $set1count;
    }
// Just take 5 elements in each
    else $requiredSet1Count = $requiredSet2Count = 5;

    return array($requiredSet1Count, $requiredSet2Count);
}

echo '<pre>';
var_export(requiredSet(1,2)); echo '<br>';
var_export(requiredSet(2,5)); echo '<br>';
var_export(requiredSet(2,7)); echo '<br>';
var_export(requiredSet(2,13)); echo '<br>';
var_export(requiredSet(13,11)); echo '<br>';
```

result

```
array ( 0 => 1, 1 => 2)
array ( 0 => 2, 1 => 5)
array ( 0 => 2, 1 => 7)
array ( 0 => 2, 1 => 8)
array ( 0 => 5, 1 => 5)
```